# Unwanted peers connecting to Altcoin

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-development, peers

I am building an altcoin using the litecoin source code.

I have removed all of the Emplace Seed calls in chainparams.cpp for DNS seeding, changed my default node communication port to port 421 and commented out all of the baked in seed nodes from chainparamsseeds.h, even added the dnsseed=0 and seed=0 to my config file and deleted my peers.dat before launching the core daemon, yet I still see clients connecting to my VPS for all different kinds of coins and swiftly ending up banned.

What am I missing? I can't find a single reason why these peers are connecting to my VPS.. Though it's not the end of the world because it has latched to my chain and only syncs blocks/headers with my other nodes, it looks very unprofessional. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

- Schwifty

Comment: Sounds like something related to your vps. Also, have you also changed to your own values for `pchMessageStart` in `chainparams.cpp`?

Comment: Hmm.. Everything with the VPS has gone smoothly to this point, and from what I can tell with netstat it is listening on the correct ports for node communication and mining. I don't believe I have changed values for pchMessageStart, I will look into this and edit my post or comment accordingly, I thank you kindly!

Comment: What I mean is your vps might be a target for bots looking for nodes.

Comment: Ah jesus, I hope not. I am going to use a different port and change pchMessageStart and bake in my VPS seed node IP the next time I rebuild so I will comment/answer if I manage to remedy the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took care of this with a combination of changing pchMessageStart values, baking my VPS seed node address into chainparamsseeds.h and adding rules to block outbound traffic to ports 9333 (and the other strange unsolicited connections to other altcoin nodes).